# Why is IIS going to the wwwroot folder instead of the one I want it to?

Tags: iis

For the default Web Site in IIS I have the following binding on the default website:

[image]

I have the following binding on the site I want to access:

[image]

When I access the site in the browser with localhost/*hostname*, I'm pointed to C:\inetpub\wwwroot*hostname*.  I have another site set up with a hostname binding that uses the same values for Port and IP Address and it points to the right place (a different folder on my C: drive).  I'm running my site locally and I have the correct hostname entry in my hosts file.  I don't want to create two separate virtual directories under a single website, I want the sites to be available as separate websites. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the hostname feature in iis, you cant use localhost to access the site any more.

Instead use `http://myhostname` and setup myhostname to point to `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file.

If you want to access the site via localhost, that implies you need to make a virtual directory, or "application" in iis.